# flutterfire configure does not show my new project

Tags: flutter, firebase

I have a base project from where I start all the new projects, this base project is already configured with a default Firebase account for tests purposes.

Well, from it, I started a new project, but now it's time to integrate this new project with its own Firebase, which is already created by the company and available for me on the Firebase console.

My problem is that when I type `flutterfire configure` on terminal this new project is not available for me to finish this configuration. How can I fix it?

Comment: did you try to choose to create a new project option? is it ok with you ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "with its own Firebase account"? Is this project under a different account than the "base project" that you've used before? If so, you will need to [change the logged in user of the Firebase CLI](https://www.google.com/search?q=change+the+logged+in+user+of+the+Firebase+CLI)

Comment: To create a new project will work

Comment: The account is the same, but different project on the Firebase. I don't need to change the logged user.